# separate one column into distinct columns

Tags: r, tidyr

Say I have the following two columns A, B per screen grab.  Col1 values are repeated.

I am trying to move col2 values to new adjacent columns, when a new cycle of numbers in col1 begins.

I have been pouring over tidyr - separate in particular, but have had no luck.

Is probably something very easy that I am missing.

Thx[image]

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Using `tidyverse` you can do `df %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = col2, names_prefix = 'col')`

Comment: Thx Ronak for sharing expertise

Comment: Ronak,  I have road tested your session, and am getting a strange error.  There are no issues in generating up to 15 new columns of data, but when I go beyond that, the first entry in line 1 (from say col17, 18, 19, .... col 50) is NA.  The original column 1 and 2 have no NAs.  I can omit NA using na.omit(file).  Unable to find anything using google - have you seen this issue before?

Comment: That is strange. We would need more information about the data and the error that you are facing. Maybe you can ask that as a new question since this question is closed by sharing data in a reproducible format and the expected output.

Comment: Ok, will do, thx

Comment: Ronak, I looked at the abscissa ranges, all were not equal.  Again, thx for sharing insights.